# a problem on permutation group and normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H$= {$e, (1, 2) (3, 4)$} and $K$= {$e, (1, 2) (3, 4), (1, 3) (2, 4), (1, 4) (2, 3)$} be subgroups of $S_4$, where $e$ denotes the identify element of $S_4$ . Then which is/are true?
1. H and K are normal subgroups of $S_4$
2. H is normal in K and K is normal in $A_4$
3. H is normal in $A_4$ but not normal in $S_4$
4. K is normal in $S_4$ , but H is not.

---

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please ask 1,2,3,4 in seperate questions

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I could not get it

Comment: H has order 2 and k has order 4

Comment: but then I have no idea

Comment: Hint: Think about how a conjugation acts on an element.

Comment: Do you know that conjugate elements in $S_n$ have the same cycle type?

Comment: I have not much idea about conjugacy classes

Answer (score 3):

Some facts that should help you in answering the questions (here $G$ is a group):

- If $L$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then it is a normal subgroup of each subgroup $M$ of $G$ such that $L\subseteq M$.
- If a subgroup $L$ of a group $G$ has index two, then $L$ is normal in $G$.
- A subgroup $L$ of $G$ is normal in $G$ if and only if for all $g\in G$ it holds that $g^{-1}Lg=L$.
- A subgroup $L$ of $S_{n}$ is normal in $S_{n}$ if and only if, for every $l\in L$, if $k\in S_{n}$ has the same cyclic structure of $l$, then $k\in L$ (this is due to the fact that two elements of $S_{n}$ belong to the same conjugacy class if and only if they have the same cyclic structure).
- If $G$ is an abelian group, every subgroup of $G$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: So $H$ is a normal subgroup of $K$.

Comment: This seems like a rather arbitrary collection of facts about normality. For example I don't see why you would include the index 2 one and also the abelian one. Also why include the definition of being normal?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Different ways to get to the same result :) I gave no proofs of the mentioned facts because I think they are either elementary or proved in any Group Theory course (or book) (and, moreover, the OP did not ask for further explanation).

Answer (score 0):

@Marco, noted you useful points. I am posting you the codes in which you can find these points better. I collect them using GAP. Now see how powerful this program is to epitomize the theoretical aspects. This is for $K$:

```
gap> g:=AlternatingGroup(IsPermGroup,4);;
gap> K:=Group((),(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,4)(2,3));;
gap> Size(K);
                                         4
gap> IsSubgroup(g, K);
                                       true
gap> IsNormal(g,K);
                                       true
```

Comment: thanks for showing how to do this in GAP, though my personal feeling is that GAP is not relevant to this question which is focused on the theoretical explanation (and Marco provided some hints that may be used on that way). Anyhow, if there is a GAP example here, I suggest to make it better: first, just `AlternatingGroup(4)` suffices since it will return permutation group by default. Second, at least `()` may be excluded from the list of generators of `K`.

Comment: by the way, which GAP installation do you use? It's interesting why the output is often centered in your examples.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: Honestly, I am new in using GAP like an infant Prof. and that's why I employ the codes differently not like the Masters. Thanks for noting that useful points. I am using the version of Alexander Hulpke's one which can be installed on Win OS (not in Dos mode). I made them centered just for looking good :-)

Comment: Thanks for details. Please note that [Alexander Hulpke's page](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~hulpke/CGT/education.html) provides installers for GAP 4.4.12 (December 2008) while the latest version as of today is GAP 4.6.4 dated May 2013. There is a [Windows installer](http://www.gap-system.org/ukrgap/wininst/) which provides a common installation procedure. Since GAP 4.5, the default shell in which GAP is running under Windows is `mintty` which is more convenient then standard "Command Line" Windows shell. So I'd encourage you to try...

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: Thanks a lot Alexander. I appreciate you. :-)

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: Dear prof. I download your version. It is great and it is better the previous Dos version. May I ask you a question? As I said, I have been working with Alexander Hulpke's version as well.After downloading your version, I over wrote the packages of yours on folders inside the packages of A. Hulpke's. I thought may be I would have a better GAP. In fact, I wanted to make his better and updated. But this is a foolish idea because it didn't work. Was that good? Sorry if I got your time. Thanks.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you've done - please feel free to contact [GAP Support](http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/People/supportgroup.html) with more details. If I am right in my guess that you moved some packages from GAP 4.6.4 under GAP 4.4.12, then this hardly will work, since many packages require newer version of GAP than 4.4.12, and are also quite interdependent as [shown on this diagram](http://alexk.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/gap/GAP_Packages.html)

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: This is exactly what I have done. Thanks Alexander. :)

Comment: Ok then. If you want to fiddle with GAP 4.4.12 installation, then the only way of adding most recent packages safely is to get those which are included in the [latest GAP 4.4.12 distribution](http://www.gap-system.org/Releases/4.4.12.html).